# encoding using ffmpeg for mac app

Tags: objective-c, macos, ffmpeg

In my mac app i am using ffmpeg library for video encoding in 4 different types of formats for iPhone, iPod, AppleTV and HD.But the encoding takes so much time and the CPU usage becomes very low.I want someone to get me any idea to maximize this CPU usage and minimize the encoding time-period so that the application may enhance the performance level.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open ended problem.  Encoding video is always a trade-off between time and quality.  To get a more specific answer, you need to be more specific about the specs you are trying to achieve and the video codec you use.

If you use x264 to encode H.264 video for instance, you might try one of the preset encode settings to see if it better suites your needs.

example,

*ffmpeg -i <source file> -vcodec libx264 -preset superfast <dest file>*

There are of course many other options x264 can be customized (-x264opts) with and there are likely equally as many parameters for other video codecs.

If you're using libavcodec manually, you can also apply different encoding options with the appropriate settings in your encoding context.